LazyColumn causing lag due to calculations for each item - How can I optimize it?
I'm experiencing significant lag when displaying a LazyColumn in my Jetpack Compose application. Each item involves some calculations (e.g., calculating the remaining time), and I load images asynchronously using Coil. This is causing performance issues, especially during scrolling.
Here's the relevant code:
I have a FeedViewState data class and a FeedViewModel that fetches a paginated list of Poll objects from the server. The LazyColumn displays this list, and when the user scrolls close to the end, I fetch more data (pagination).
@Composable
fun FeedComp(
    mainViewModel: MainViewModel,
    mainHomeVM: MainHomeViewModel,
    showBottomSheet: MutableState<Boolean>,
    navControllerMain: NavController,
) {
    // Initial data fetch
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        feedVM.GetFeedFunctionality(mainViewModel)
    }

    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.blur(if (showBottomSheet.value) 15.dp else 0.dp),
        topBar = {
            MainHomeTopBarComp(mainViewModel = mainViewModel, showBottomSheet)
        },
    ) { paddingValues ->
        Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            LazyColumn(
                state = listState,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(paddingValues)
                    .background(Color.White),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
            ) {
                item { Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp)) }
                items(state.FeedList) { poll ->
                    PollItem(
                        poll = poll,
                        mainViewModel = mainViewModel,
                        navControllerMain = navControllerMain,
                        pollReportId = pollReportId,
                        showManagementDialog = showManagementDialog,
                        managementOwner = managementOwner,
                        feedVM = feedVM
                    )  // Each PollItem involves calculations and Coil image loading
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Pagination - fetch more data when user scrolls close to the end
    LaunchedEffect(listState.firstVisibleItemIndex) {
        val visibleItemCount = listState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.size
        val totalItemCount = listState.layoutInfo.totalItemsCount
        val lastVisibleItemIndex = listState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()?.index ?: 0

        if (lastVisibleItemIndex >= totalItemCount - 3 && !state.loading) {
            feedVM.GetFeedFunctionality(mainViewModel)
        }
    }
}


ViewModel and Data:
data class FeedViewState(
    val loading: Boolean = false,
    var FeedList: List<Poll> = emptyList(),
)

@HiltViewModel
class FeedViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val feedRepository: FeedRepository,
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(FeedViewState())
    val state = _state.asStateFlow()

    private var currentPage by mutableStateOf(1)

    fun GetFeedFunctionality(mainViewModel: MainViewModel) {
        if (state.value.loading) return

        val pageSize = 10
        val token = "Bearer ${mainViewModel.GetToken()}"
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _state.update { it.copy(loading = true) }
            feedRepository.getFeed(token = token, pageSize = pageSize, pageNumber = currentPage)
                .onRight { response ->
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        response.body()?.data?.polls?.let { polls ->
                            _state.update {
                                it.copy(
                                    FeedList = it.FeedList + polls
                                )
                            }
                            currentPage++
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onLeft { error ->
                    Log.e("FeedViewModel", "Network error: ${error.error.message}")
                }
            _state.update { it.copy(loading = false) }
        }
    }
}


PollItem Composable:
Each PollItem involves some calculations and image loading using Coil.
each poll(object) is a data class that i gotten from api
data class Poll(
    val commentCloesed: Boolean,
    val createdAt: String,
    val endedAt: String,
    val id: String,
    var isPollUp: Boolean,
    var likes: Int,
    val maximumParticipate: Int,
    var numberofcommnets: Int,
    var numberofshare: Int,
    val numberofviews: Int,
    val options: List<Option>,
    val owner: Owner?,
    val isOwner:Boolean,
    var participate: Int,
    val pollUrl: String,
    val polltype: Int,
    val question: String,
    val isAlphaUser:Boolean,
    val isAlpha:Boolean,
    val isSensitive:Boolean,
    var status: Int,
    val tags: List<String>,
    val topics: List<Topic>,
    var user: List<User>,
    var userCommentedPoll: Boolean,
    var userLike: Boolean,
    var userReShare: Boolean,
    val userViewedPoll: Boolean,
    var userVotedOnPoll: Boolean,
    val votingtype: Int,
    var deleted :Boolean = false
)

@Composable
fun PollItem(
    poll: Poll,
    mainViewModel: MainViewModel,
    navControllerMain: NavController,
    pollReportId: MutableState<String>,
    showManagementDialog: MutableState<Boolean>,
    managementOwner: MutableState<Boolean>,
    feedVM: FeedViewModel
) {
    val screenHeight = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp
    val screenWidth = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp
    if (!poll.deleted) {
        Column(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(end = 16.dp, start = 16.dp, bottom = 8.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
                .background(backgroundpollcard)
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTapGestures(
                        onTap = {
                            mainViewModel.rememberedPoll.value = poll
                            navControllerMain.navigate("pollPage/${poll.id}")
                        },
                        onLongPress = {
                            pollReportId.value = poll.id
                            managementOwner.value = poll.isOwner
                            showManagementDialog.value = true

                        }
                    )
                }
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            //polled up by who
            if (poll.isPollUp) {
                Row(
                    Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
                ) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
                            .border(1.dp, textSecondary, RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
                            .background(backgroundTabs)
                            .padding(8.dp),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                    ) {
                        Row(
                            Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                        ) {
                            Icon(
                                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.unpollup),
                                contentDescription = "pollup icon",
                                tint = textSecondary,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .size(20.dp)
                            )
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                            Text(
                                fontFamily = sfPro,
                                text = "PollUpped by ",
                                fontSize = 12.sp,
                                //letterSpacing = (-0.41).sp,
                                lineHeight = 14.sp,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight(400),
                                color = textSecondary
                            )
                            val currentUserId =
                                mainViewModel.singedInProfileResponse.value?.data?.id
                            val userName =
                                poll.user.find { it.userId == currentUserId }
                                    ?.let { "You" }
                                    ?: poll.user.firstOrNull()?.userName
                                    ?: poll.user[0].userName
                            Text(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .sizeIn(maxWidth = 100.dp)
                                // .background(Color.LightGray)
                                ,
                                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                                fontFamily = sfPro,
                                text = "$userName",
                                maxLines = 1,
                                fontSize = 12.sp,
                                //letterSpacing = (-0.41).sp,
                                lineHeight = 14.sp,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight(600),
                                color = textSecondary
                            )
                            if (poll.user.size > 1) {
                                Text(
                                    fontFamily = sfPro,
                                    text = " and ",
                                    fontSize = 12.sp,
                                    //letterSpacing = (-0.41).sp,
                                    lineHeight = 14.sp,
                                    fontWeight = FontWeight(400),
                                    color = textSecondary
                                )
                                Text(
                                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                                    fontFamily = sfPro,
                                    text = "${poll.user.size - 1}",
                                    maxLines = 1,
                                    fontSize = 12.sp,
                                    //letterSpacing = (-0.41).sp,
                                    lineHeight = 14.sp,
                                    fontWeight = FontWeight(600),
                                    color = textSecondary
                                )
                                Text(
                                    fontFamily = sfPro,
                                    text = "${if (poll.user.size - 1 > 1) "others" else "other"}",
                                    fontSize = 12.sp,
                                    //letterSpacing = (-0.41).sp,
                                    lineHeight = 14.sp,
                                    fontWeight = FontWeight(400),
                                    color = textSecondary
                                )

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(24.dp))
            }

            //profile & progress
            Row(
                Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
            ) {
                Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(40.dp)
                            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(100))
                            .background(Color.LightGray)
                    ) {
                        if (poll.owner != null) {
                            if (poll.owner.pictureUrl != null && poll.owner.pictureUrl != "") {
                                AsyncImage(
                                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                                    model = poll.owner?.pictureUrl,
                                    contentDescription = "poll owner profile image",
                                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                                )
                            } else {
                                Image(
                                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.defaultprof),
                                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                                    contentDescription = "poll owner profile image",
                                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                                )
                            }

                        } else {
                            Image(
                                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.anonymous_emblem),
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                                contentDescription = "poll owner profile image",
                                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                            )
                        }

                    }
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                    if (poll.owner != null) {
                        Column(Modifier.offset(y = -2.dp)) {
                            Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                                poll.owner?.firstName?.let {
                                    Text(
                                        fontFamily = sfPro,
                                        text = it,
                                        fontSize = 16.sp,
                                        //letterSpacing = (-0.41).sp,
                                        lineHeight = 19.sp,
                                        fontWeight = FontWeight(500),
                                        color = textSecondary
                                    )
                                }
                                if (poll.isAlphaUser) {
                                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                                    Image(
                                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.alpha),
                                        contentDescription = "alpha sign",
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .size(17.dp)
                                    )

                                }
                            }

                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
                            Text(
                                fontFamily = sfPro,
                                text = "@" + poll.owner?.userName,
                                fontSize = 10.sp,
                                // letterSpacing = (-0.41).sp,
                                lineHeight = 11.sp,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight(500),
                                color = textThirt
                            )
                        }
                    } else {
                        Text(
                            fontFamily = sfPro,
                            text = "Anonymous Poll",
                            fontSize = 16.sp,
                            //letterSpacing = (-0.41).sp,
                            lineHeight = 19.sp,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight(500),
                            color = textSecondary
                        )
                        //todo:inja YOU biyad , fix condition
                        if (poll.isOwner == true) {
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                            Text(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .border(
                                        0.5.dp,
                                        color = textSecondary,
                                        RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
                                    )
                                    .padding(
                                        start = 6.dp,
                                        end = 6.dp
                                    ),
                                fontFamily = sfPro,
                                text = "You",
                                fontSize = 8.sp,
                                //letterSpacing = (-0.41).sp,
                                lineHeight = 19.sp,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight(500),
                                color = textSecondary
                            )
                        }

                    }


                }

                Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                    if (poll.status == 1) {
                        CircularProgressIndicator(
                            modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp),
                            strokeWidth = 2.dp,
                            color = feedVM.timeRemaining(poll.endedAt).second,
                            trackColor = strokesVoteTime,
                            strokeCap = StrokeCap.Round,
                            progress = {
                                feedVM.calculatePercentage(
                                    startDate = poll.createdAt,
                                    endDate = poll.endedAt
                                )
                            }
                        )

                        Box {
                            Text(
                                fontFamily = sfPro,
                                text = "${feedVM.timeRemaining(poll.endedAt).first}",
                                fontSize = 10.sp,
                                //letterSpacing = (-0.41).sp,
                                lineHeight = 12.sp,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight(500),
                                color = if (poll.status == 0) textthird else feedVM.timeRemaining(
                                    poll.endedAt
                                ).second
                            )
                        }
                    } else {
                        CircularProgressIndicator(
                            modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp),
                            strokeWidth = 2.dp,
                            color = textthird,
                            trackColor = strokesVoteTime,
                            strokeCap = StrokeCap.Round,
                            progress = {
                                1f
                            }
                        )

                        Box {
                            Text(
                                fontFamily = sfPro,
                                text = "Ended",
                                fontSize = 10.sp,
                                //letterSpacing = (-0.41).sp,
                                lineHeight = 12.sp,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight(500),
                                color = textthird
                            )
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
            //question
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                HashtagText(
                    text = poll.question,
                    onHashtagClick = { hashtag ->
                        navControllerMain.navigate("pollPage/${poll.id}")
                        println("Hashtag clicked: $hashtag")
                    },
                    onTextClick = {
                        navControllerMain.navigate("pollPage/${poll.id}")
                        println("Non-hashtag text clicked!")
                    }
                )
            }

            //first option
            if (poll.options.isNotEmpty()) {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                if (poll.options[0].type == 0) {//means its text poll
                    Row(
                        Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                    ) {

                        CustomRadioButton(
                            isSelected = mutableStateOf(poll.options[0].userChoose),
                            onClick = {},
                            borderColor = textthird,
                            size = 16.dp,
                            dotColor = textthird,
                            isEnabled = false
                        )
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                        Column {
                            Text(
                                fontFamily = sfPro,
                                text = poll.options[0].title,
                                fontSize = 14.sp,
                                //letterSpacing = (-0.41).sp,
                                lineHeight = 17.sp,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight(500),
                                color = textSecondary
                            )
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .height(2.dp)
                                    .background(if (poll.options[0].userChoose) textthird else strokesVoteTime)
                            )
                        }
                    }
                } else {//means its image poll
                    // Text(text = "${(screenHeight*9/ 40)}")
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .height(screenHeight * 9 / 40)
                            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
                            .background(Color.LightGray)
                    ) {

                        AsyncImage(
                            model = poll.options[0].data,
                            contentDescription = null,
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                        )


                    }
                }
            }

            //more option(s)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
            Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                Text(
                    fontFamily = sfPro,
                    text = "${poll.options.size - 1} more ${if (poll.options.size - 1 == 1) "option" else "options"}",
                    fontSize = 12.sp,
                    //letterSpacing = (-0.41).sp,
                    lineHeight = 15.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(400),
                    color = textthird
                )
            }

            //like comment
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
            Row(
                Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
            ) {

                //alpha
                if (poll.isAlpha) {
                    Text(
                        fontFamily = sfPro,
                        text = "Alpha",
                        fontSize = 12.sp,
                        //letterSpacing = (-0.41).sp,
                        lineHeight = 15.sp,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight(600),
                        color = textImportant
                    )
                }
                //comment
                if (!poll.commentCloesed) {
                    Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                        Icon(
                            modifier = Modifier.size(17.dp),
                            painter = if (poll.userCommentedPoll)
                                painterResource(id = R.drawable.comment)
                            else
                                painterResource(id = R.drawable.uncomment),
                            tint = if (poll.status == 1) if (poll.userCommentedPoll) iconsFunctionalityComment else iconsFunctionalityDefault else textthird,
                            contentDescription = "icon"
                        )
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(4.dp))
                        Text(
                            fontFamily = sfPro,
                            text = "${poll.numberofcommnets}",
                            fontSize = 10.sp,
                            //letterSpacing = (-0.41).sp,
                            lineHeight = 12.sp,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight(400),
                            color = iconsFunctionalityDefault
                        )
                    }

                }

                //like
                Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                    Icon(
                        modifier = Modifier.size(17.dp),
                        painter = if (poll.userLike)
                            painterResource(id = R.drawable.like)
                        else
                            painterResource(id = R.drawable.unlike),
                        tint = if (poll.status == 1) if (poll.userLike) iconsFunctionalityLike else iconsFunctionalityDefault else textthird,
                        contentDescription = "icon"
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(4.dp))
                    Text(
                        fontFamily = sfPro,
                        text = "${poll.likes}",
                        fontSize = 10.sp,
                        //letterSpacing = (-0.41).sp,
                        lineHeight = 12.sp,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight(400),
                        color = iconsFunctionalityDefault
                    )
                }

                //pollup
                Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                    Icon(
                        modifier = Modifier.size(17.dp),
                        painter = if (poll.userReShare)
                            painterResource(id = R.drawable.pollup)
                        else
                            painterResource(id = R.drawable.unpollup),
                        tint = if (poll.status == 1) if (poll.userReShare) iconsFunctionalityPollup else iconsFunctionalityDefault else textthird,
                        contentDescription = "icon"
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(4.dp))
                    Text(
                        fontFamily = sfPro,
                        text = "${poll.numberofshare}",
                        fontSize = 10.sp,
                        //letterSpacing = (-0.41).sp,
                        lineHeight = 12.sp,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight(400),
                        color = iconsFunctionalityDefault
                    )
                }

                //voters
                Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                    Icon(
                        modifier = Modifier.size(17.dp),
                        painter = if (poll.userVotedOnPoll)
                            painterResource(id = R.drawable.vote)
                        else
                            painterResource(id = R.drawable.unvote),
                        tint = if (poll.status == 1) if (poll.userVotedOnPoll) iconsFunctionalityVoter else iconsFunctionalityDefault else textthird,
                        contentDescription = "icon"
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(4.dp))
                    Text(
                        fontFamily = sfPro,
                        text = "${poll.participate}",
                        fontSize = 10.sp,
                        //letterSpacing = (-0.41).sp,
                        lineHeight = 12.sp,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight(400),
                        color = iconsFunctionalityDefault
                    )
                }

            }

        }
    }
}

My Issue:
The LazyColumn causes lag, especially during scrolling.
Each PollItem requires calculations, and images are loaded asynchronously using Coil.

Please include code for proper answer.

@BenjyTec post edited . thanks.

@Akshat post edited . thanks.

@AliFarhad Please show us your PollItem implementation. The issue might be there.

@BenjyTec Thank you for your  assistance! I've edited my post

@AliFarhad Wow, that is a lot of code... Have you tried running the app in release mode as described here? https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/performance Also, you can try to gradually remove code from your PollItem Composable and see where the lag stops to occur. Then include the minimal code here that is needed to reproduce the issue. This will greatly improve your chances of getting an answer here.

Please reduce your code to a [mre]. Make sure it reproduces the issue but make it as small as possible. Most of the code your currently posted has nothing to do with the issue, please remove it.

@BenjyTec thanks for your advice. release mode fix all of my application issues for lists and animations. <3

The issue is resolved when I build the app in release mode. Debug mode was causing performance overhead, but switching to release mode fixed the lag and improved scrolling performance significantly.
